# Fetch values from multiple lines and combine

Tags: splunk

We forwarded app logs to splunk from different host and different sources.

```
Thread1 requestId=aUniqueID1 table=Table1

Thread1 size=2gb

Thread2 requestId=aUniqueID5 some other log

Thread1 requestId=aUniqueID1 some other log

Thread2 size=5gb

Thread1 requestId=aUniqueID2 table=Table2

Thread1 size=4gb

Thread1- requestId=aUniqueID3 table=Table3
```

Here I want to a table of request Id and size

```
aUniqueId1  2gb

aUniqueId2  4gb

aUniqueID5 5gb
```

Basically, thread name stays the same per host, but the same thread will be reused once a request is completed.

Can someone help write a Splunk query?

When a request comes, a log can be identified with thread name (Thread1,Thread2,etc)

Basically for a transaction, most log statements have `requestId` and I know the start and end times, thus I know the size within that time range (by host and sourcetype and thread name)

Comment: It seems like a "transaction" begins with "requestId=" and ends with "size=", but what about `aUniqueID1 some otherlog`?  It comes after a size so doesn't fit the pattern.

Comment: Will "*otherlog*" events ever taken into account? Do "*otherlog*" events have non-empty value for `table`?

Comment: For a transaction, some statement doesn’t have requestId and have size in it which I want along with requestId

Answer (score 0):

Here is a run-anywhere example of how to do that.

````
| makeresults | eval data="Thread1 requestId=aUniqueID1 table=Table1
Thread1 size=2gb
Thread1 requestId=aUniqueID1 some otherlog
Thread1 requestId=aUniqueID2 table=Table2
Thread1 size=4gb
Thread1 requestId=aUniqueID3 table=Table3" | eval data=split(data,"
") | mvexpand data | eval _raw=data
```Everything above sets up test data.  Omit when using live data```
```Combine requestId and size lines```
| transaction startswith="requestId" endswith="size"
```Parse the results```
| extract kvdelim=" ", pairdelim="="
```Display request ID and corresponding size```
| table requestId size
````